# What does "bad for the greater good" mean?

Tags: meaning

I heard Kevin Spacey in The House of Cards say "bad for the greater good". Can anyone tell me what that means??

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Do you have some thoughts as to what the phrase might mean?

Comment: @rajah9 thank you! I know that greater good means something good for all mankind and collectively beneficial. Am I right?

Comment: The character is corrupt and manipulative in the extreme. He means you do a little bad for the sake of the bigger picture. So the result is good for more people in the end.

Comment: @rajah9 But the word 'bad' in the beginning caused the confusion.

Comment: Sometimes people will claim that they are doing something for the greater good (which is collectively beneficial) at the cost of something bad (for an individual or a small group). (For example, a tax may be bad for the greater good of society.) However, when Kevin Spacey is using this, the "bad" is bad, and the "greater good" is a weak or absent justification.

Comment: I'm reading through the quotes at http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/tag/greater-good. You might find the quotes helpful in reasoning out this oxymoron.

Comment: Without further context, this is impossible to answer.  Perhaps those familiar with the show will recognize the scene, but for those that do not know the circumstances, the sentence fragment provided could got into a sentence like, “Sometimes you have to be a tiny bit bad for the greater good” or it could go into one like, “You shouldn’t do that because it would be bad for the greater good.”

Comment: I agree. However, I think the first option is obviously the one, because you see it written on cover photos as quotes, and the second option couldn't possibly make sense because the character is known as a very dominant and sly person. Just like you said,  it seems vague when the character is not known, which explains what happened with me. Thank you for commenting! @Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The character is saying that [the ends justify the means](http://www.publicbookshelf.com/public_html/Outline_of_Great_Books_Volume_I/machiavell_bfa.html).  Good ends via bad means.

Answer (score 1):

"*Bad for the greater good*" is synonymous with the well-known proverb "*all's well that ends well.*"

> **[all's well that ends well](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/all%27s_well_that_ends_well)** (phrase, proverb)
>
> ***If the outcome of a situation is happy, this compensates for any previous difficulty or unpleasantness.***

Note : This proverb was used as a title for one of William Shakespeare's comedies.